# Unknown Characters when reading CSV from URL in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, encoding

I am trying to read a CSV from URL in Angular 4 using the following code:

```
this.http.get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
    .map(r => r.blob())
    .subscribe(
    (response) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            console.log(reader.result);
        }, false);

        reader.readAsText(response);
    }, 
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

However, it returns some unknown characters like:

> �Z�9����NV�8ʩ����ji

How do I decode this into proper string ?

Just to add- If I hit the URL directly in the browser, it downloads the file.

Comment: is may cause by encodage issue, let try : `reader.readAsText(response, '<ENCODAGE HERE>');`

Comment: @Yanis-git What encoding should I give ?

Comment: is base on your csv file, check on google how to find original encodage.